# limiting user calls to a hub method

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

If I am developing a chat application with SignalR and is there a way to limit the number of chat messages allowed sent at a certain time so users cant spam.  It doesn't need to be a super complicated system, just needs to limit maybe 60-100 messages a minute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing intrinsic to SignalR to help with this, you would have to track and do rate limiting yourself within the Hub method implementation today. In the future you would probably want to implement this as a sort of "filter" (like ASP.NET MVC Action Filters), but the specification for filters in SignalR is just starting to be fleshed out now. If you're interested, you can read up on and participate in this discussion [here on GitHub](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/548).